# getResourceAsStream() returns a stream whose content is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I have a small Java project in eclipse. The project  has an src and bin folder (typical) and src is added to class path. I am running on Windows.

The following call works:

```
System.out.println(TestINI.class.getResource("happytest.ini"));
```

It prints the path of file:

```
file:/D:/work/baton/Touch/JTouch/bin/com/interra/tests/happytest.ini
```

I checked that the contents of ini file mentioned above have expected content.

But reading from the file as follows:

```
InputStream is = TestINI.class.getResourceAsStream("happytest.ini");
```

gives me an input stream which has no content. i.e. it returns a file with zero bytes.

My Eclipse is 3.6 Helios 64 bit running on Windows 7.

Google searching revealed cases where the resource path or input stream was null but that is not the case with me.

The class path entries are as follows:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
... other class path entries for libraries like ini4j
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
```

Comment: When you "checked the contents of the ini file" did you look in the bin folder or the src folder?  I suspect you may not have done a full rebuild and/or the ini file did not get copied into the bin directory structure.  Note that putting the src directory tree into the classpath is NOT the answer, as it generally won't be available at runtime.

Comment: "gives me an input stream which has no content. i.e. it returns a file with zero bytes." how did you try this out?

Comment: I just had a test class in same directory with a static main. The test class had: InputStream s = TestIni.class.getResourceAsStream("happytest.ini"); and then I read from the input stream s.

Comment: Thanx Jim. At that time, I could see that there was a corresponding file in the bin directory but I didn't carefully check its contents. Later on I figured out that eclipse had not updated the happytest.ini in bin directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what  Jim Garrison said - you edited the file in 'src' and read from 'bin'...

Comment: yes I agree.. I was just getting confused with the way eclipse worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your example and it worked for me with `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` as well. I know that it is not reassuring.

Anyway, it is interesting that your stream has no content, try this out:

```
new FileInputStream(new File(TestINI.class.getResource("happytest.ini").toURI()));
```

If you read this stream and there is no content, then something is wrong with your file. For testing I called the `read()` method on the `Stream`s.

Comment: That will only work if the resource is an actual file on disk, which it might not be.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem. For the ini files, my eclipse was opening notepad by default. The changes I made through notepad in the ini file, they didn't reflect on eclipse side properly. Today when I edited the file through Eclipse's Text Editor, they reflected properly in the getResourceAsStream() calls. Essentially after editing through notepad, the resource was out of sync in eclipse.

Comment: I just wasted hours for a more fancy case. I've a program that read certain files from the JAR where it is contained and writes them into a target directory in the file system. Because of certain needs, I've the working directory in the classpath and a test where those files are written in the working directory. The result is getResourceAsStream() fetches files from the working directory just after they're created, so apparently it reads and write empty files. Beware in case you find yourself on a similar situation.